# Linq.GroupByにおけるGroupingのキー項目の動的な指定について

Tags: c#, linq

System.Linq.GroupBy()メソッドについて、Groupingのキー項目を
動的に指定するにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。
対応方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示お願いいたします。

なお、.NET Frameworkは4.5を使用しています。
Groupingの結果、keyは一意になる場合に限り出力し、
valueは、常にサマリ値を出力するという制限を設けております。

```
// メイン処理
void main()
{
    // 初期化
    groupByList = new List<GroupByEntity>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        groupByList.Add(new GroupByEntity()
        {
            key1 = "key1" + Math.Floor((double)(i / 2)).ToString(),
            key2 = "key2" + Math.Floor((double)(i / 3)).ToString(),
            key3 = "key3" + Math.Floor((double)(i / 4)).ToString(),
            key4 = "key4" + Math.Floor((double)(i / 4) + 2).ToString(),
            key5 = "key5" + Math.Floor((double)(i / 5)).ToString(),
            value1 = 10 + i,
            value2 = 20 + i,
            value3 = 30 + i
        });
    }

    outputToConsole(groupByList, "初期値");

    // 動的GroupBy
    Type groupByType = typeof(GroupByEntity);
    ParameterExpression groupByParam = Expression.Parameter(groupByType, "m");

    MemberExpression key1Member = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(groupByParam,groupByType.GetMember("key1").First());
    MemberExpression key2Member = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(groupByParam,groupByType.GetMember("key2").First());
    MemberExpression key3Member = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(groupByParam,groupByType.GetMember("key3").First());
    MemberExpression key4Member = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(groupByParam,groupByType.GetMember("key4").First());
    MemberExpression key5Member = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(groupByParam,groupByType.GetMember("key5").First());

    List<MemberExpression> keyMembers = new List<MemberExpression>();

    //---修正前ここから---
    //keyMembers.Add(key1Member);
    //keyMembers.Add(key2Member);
    //
    //// ■■このkeyMembersを、下のgroupingにラムダ式として設定したい（以下のように）■■
    //---修正前ここまで---
    //---修正後ここから---
    if (条件１) keyMembers.Add(key1Member);
    if (条件２) keyMembers.Add(key2Member);
    if (条件３) keyMembers.Add(key3Member);
    if (条件４) keyMembers.Add(key4Member);
    if (条件５) keyMembers.Add(key5Member);

    // ■■このkeyMembersを、下のgroupingにラムダ式として設定したい
    // ■■例えば、上記条件１・条件２がtrueとなる場合は、下記groupingと同等になるようにしたい
    //---修正後ここまで---

    Expression<Func<GroupByEntity, dynamic>> grouping = (m => new { m.key1, m.key2 });

    List<GroupByEntity> list = groupByList
        .GroupBy(grouping.Compile())
        .Select(m => new GroupByEntity()
        {
            key1 = selectUniqueValue(m.Select(val => val.key1)),
            key2 = selectUniqueValue(m.Select(val => val.key2)),
            key3 = selectUniqueValue(m.Select(val => val.key3)),
            key4 = selectUniqueValue(m.Select(val => val.key4)),
            key5 = selectUniqueValue(m.Select(val => val.key5)),
            value1 = m.Sum(val => val.value1),
            value2 = m.Sum(val => val.value2),
            value3 = m.Sum(val => val.value3)
        })
        .ToList();

    outputToConsole(list, "結果");
}

// リスト内の文字列が一意になる場合に限り、その値を戻り値とする
private string selectUniqueValue(IEnumerable<string> list)
{
    if (list.Distinct().Count() == 1)
    {
        return list.First();
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

// コンソールへの出力
private void outputToConsole(List<GroupByEntity> list, string title)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("---{0}---", title));

    foreach (GroupByEntity row in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(row.createOutputLine());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("------------");
}

// Grouping用属性
public class GroupByEntity
{
    public string key1;
    public string key2;
    public string key3;
    public string key4;
    public string key5;
    public int value1;
    public int value2;
    public int value3;

    // 出力用文字列作成
    public string createOutputLine()
    {
        List<string> ret = new List<string>();

        ret.Add(createOutputValue(key1));
        ret.Add(createOutputValue(key2));
        ret.Add(createOutputValue(key3));
        ret.Add(createOutputValue(key4));
        ret.Add(createOutputValue(key5));
        ret.Add(createOutputValue(value1.ToString()));
        ret.Add(createOutputValue(value2.ToString()));
        ret.Add(createOutputValue(value3.ToString()));

        return string.Join(",", ret);
    }

    // 出力用文字列整形
    public string createOutputValue(string value)
    {
        return value.PadRight(7);
    }
}
```

Comment: サンプルコード内で、質問の中核となる部分がいい加減でした。  
質問内容が不明瞭になってしまっていたため、修正しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問の意図がいまいち理解できませんでした。何か問題があるわけではなく、既に実現できているわけですよね？ Expressionを使いたくないということでしょうか？
とりあえず思い付いたコードを挙げますので、何か参考になればと。

GroupBy()は[keySelectorの他にcomparerも受け取るオーバーロード](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/bb534334(v=vs.110).aspx)が存在します。希望するcomparerを動的に作れば実現できそうに思います。

```
class GroupByEntityEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<GroupByEntity> {
    public bool CompareKey1 { get; set; }
    public bool CompareKey2 { get; set; }
    public bool CompareKey3 { get; set; }
    public bool CompareKey4 { get; set; }
    public bool CompareKey5 { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(GroupByEntity x, GroupByEntity y) {
        if (CompareKey1 && !x.key1.Equals(y.key1)) return false;
        if (CompareKey2 && !x.key2.Equals(y.key2)) return false;
        if (CompareKey3 && !x.key3.Equals(y.key3)) return false;
        if (CompareKey4 && !x.key4.Equals(y.key4)) return false;
        if (CompareKey5 && !x.key5.Equals(y.key5)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(GroupByEntity obj) {
        int hashCode = 0;
        if (CompareKey1) hashCode ^= obj.key1.GetHashCode();
        if (CompareKey2) hashCode ^= obj.key2.GetHashCode();
        if (CompareKey3) hashCode ^= obj.key3.GetHashCode();
        if (CompareKey4) hashCode ^= obj.key4.GetHashCode();
        if (CompareKey5) hashCode ^= obj.key5.GetHashCode();
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

を利用して

```
// 修正後
var comparer = new GroupByEntityEqualityComparer();
if (条件１) comparer.CompareKey1 = true;
if (条件２) comparer.CompareKey2 = true;
if (条件３) comparer.CompareKey3 = true;
if (条件４) comparer.CompareKey4 = true;
if (条件５) comparer.CompareKey5 = true;
// ここまで
var list = groupByList
    .GroupBy(m => m, comparer)
    .Select(m => new GroupByEntity() {
        key1 = selectUniqueValue(m.Select(val => val.key1)),
        key2 = selectUniqueValue(m.Select(val => val.key2)),
        key3 = selectUniqueValue(m.Select(val => val.key3)),
        key4 = selectUniqueValue(m.Select(val => val.key4)),
        key5 = selectUniqueValue(m.Select(val => val.key5)),
        value1 = m.Max(val => val.value1),
        value2 = m.Max(val => val.value2),
        value3 = m.Max(val => val.value3)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: ご回答くださいましてありがとうございます。質問内容がいい加減だったため、不明瞭な質問となってしまい申し訳ありません。ご提示頂いたコードを取り込んで、希望通りの動作を確認しました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

> m => new { m.key1, m.key2 }

これは`Expression.MemberInit`で生成できる式ですが、匿名クラスは動的に作成できませんので`Tuple`を返す`Expression`を作成してください。

実際にgrouping相当のExpressionを作るには以下のような手順となります。

```
if (keyMembers.Count == 0)
{
    // TODO:
}
else if (keyMembers.Count == 1)
{
    var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(groupByType, keyMembers[0].Type);
    grouping = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, keyMembers[0], groupByParam);
}
else
{
    Type genericDefinition;
    switch (keyMembers.Count)
    {
        case 2: genericDefinition = typeof(Tuple<,>); break;
        case 3: genericDefinition = typeof(Tuple<,,>); break;
        case 4: genericDefinition = typeof(Tuple<,,,>); break;
        default: genericDefinition = typeof(Tuple<,,,,>); break;
    }
    var constructed = genericDefinition.MakeGenericType(keyMembers.Select(_ => _.Type).ToArray());
    var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(groupByType, constructed);

    grouping = Expression.Lambda(
                   delegateType,
                   Expression.New(
                       constructed.GetConstructor(constructed.GetGenericArguments()),
                       keyMembers.ToArray()),
                   groupByParam);
}
```

Comment: ご回答くださいましてありがとうございます。質問内容がいい加減で、不明瞭な質問になって申し訳ありません。ラムダ式に設定しなければならないと思い込んでしまったために、項目数自体が可変になることについての対応に苦慮していました。Tupleを用いたNewExpressionの生成について大変勉強になりました。ただ、Tupleの場合、項目数が増加して9個以上になった場合に対応しきれないのでは？と感じております。

Comment: そういう場合は`Tuple‘8`の第8要素に別のTupleを入れ子にすることが想定されています。https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/dd383325%28v=vs.110%29.aspx これに沿うなら`keyMembers`の数が8以下になるまで末尾の数要素を`Expression.New`でTupleの式にまとめていけば良いかと思います。

Comment: 引き続きのご回答ありがとうございます。実を申しますと、業務で当質問に似た状況になっており質問した次第なのですが、実際には項目数が0～25ほどの可変で、今後も項目数や各項目の型の仕様変更が予想されており（勘弁してくれという感じですが…）、その際の対応が自分ではない可能性があるのです。知識が乏しい作業者に回る可能性もあるため、仕様を実現しつつ、深く理解せずともとりあえずコピペでなんとか対応できるようにコーディングしたいと考えておりました。ご回答いただいた内容は大変勉強になりましたし、とても感謝しておりますが…今回は見送らねばならないのが現状です。本当に申し訳ありませんが、今後もよろしくお願いします。